# Conditions when applying Gauss's law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, gauss-law, textbook-erratum

While reading a text book on EM fields (Engineering Electromagnetic, Nathan Ida, Springer), I came across a passage that describes conditions necessary to apply Gauss's law in order to find electric field strength. One of these conditions said that the angle between electric field and the surface must be constant. Then, they go on to use a diagram to explain what happens for various cases ( such as a  field  perpendicular to the surface) but for figure 4.3b they say that $E.ds3=E$ however $E.ds4= 0$. But if you look at the diagram shouldn't they produce the same result?  In both cases, it looks like the angle between the electric field and the surface is 90 degrees. I guess my question is why do these two dot product result in different answers? [image: figure from the text book]

Comment: For electric fields, the Gaussian surface should be selected such that the electric field strength is constant everywhere on that surface.  This means that a point charge dictates that you use a Gaussian sphere, with the charge located at the center of the sphere.  For an infinite line charge, you need an infinitely long cylinder with the line charge located at the center.  Other charge configurations will obviously require different Gaussian surfaces in order to satisfy the "constant field" constraint.

Comment: -1. Unclear. The text below the diagram says that $E_0.ds_3=E_0.ds_4=0$. The body text also says that *If the electric field intensity is parallel to the surface, the scalar produce $E.ds$ is zero*. Where are you getting that they are different?

Comment: Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

In the specific example of your question, $\vec E\cdot d\vec s_3$ should be $\vec E\cdot d\vec s_4=0$ as they both perpendicular to $\vec E_0$, and I would suspect a typo in your book, as you already suspect.  In addition $\vec E\cdot d\vec s_2= - \vec E\cdot d\vec s_1$ by geometry; the net flux is $0$ because your "box" does not contain any charge.  However, clearly $\vec E$ is non-zero so Gauss' law does not help you much: this is because $\vec E\cdot d\vec s$ is *NOT* constant on your surface.

Actually Gauss's law 
$$
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec s=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}
$$
is always applicable but not always useful to determine the electric field, as your example on the right clearly illustrates. Basically, the left hand side is the net flux of $\vec E$, but this is not often a quantity of interest.

Because $\vec E\cdot d\vec s= \vert \vec E\vert ds\,\cos\theta_s$, you need first to find a surface on which $\vert \vec E\vert$ is constant, so you can pull out $\vert \vec E\vert$ from the integral, i.e. write 
$$
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec s=\vert \vec E\vert \oint ds\cos\theta_s
$$
Next you need to be able to compute $ds\cos\theta_s$, remembering that $\theta_s$ is the angle between $\vec E$ and $d\vec s$ at every location $s$ on your surface.  In your specific example however $\oint ds\cos\theta_s=0$, and you get no help in finding $\vert \vec E\vert$.

The integral $\oint ds\cos\theta_s$ is most easily done when $\theta_s=0$ everywhere, i.e. when the field on the Gaussian surface is everywhere parallel to the surface element $d\vec S$.
If this is the case then 
$$
\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec s=\vert \vec E\vert \times S=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}
$$
and you can solve for $\vert \vec E\vert$ at every point on the surface.  Implicit here is that the direction of $\vec E$ is known on your surface since you can determined $\theta_s$ everywhere.

Note that finding a surface on which $\vec E$ has constant magnitude is rare unless the charge distribution has some geometrical symmetry, like spherical, cylindrical or planar.

An analogy would be that $\oint \vec E\cdot d\vec s$ is the net amount of money you have in your pocket.  The condition of finding a surface where $\vert \vec E \vert$ is constant is like a condition that all the coins in your pocket have the same value.  The surface $S$ would be the number of coins.  In the analogy, the total amount of money would be the number of coins $S \times$ the nominal value of any one coin $\vert \vec E\vert$, or $Q/\epsilon_0$ on the right hand side of Gauss' law in the electric field example.  If the sum total is known, and the number of coins is known, you can recover the value of each coin by taking the total and diving by the number of coins.  The analogy shows how essential is the condition that all coins have the same value, (i.e. $\vert \vec E\vert =$ constant in the electric field example).  If the coins do not have the same value, you cannot (in general) reconstruct the value of any coin from the sum total and the number of coins only.  (Of course I'm assuming you have sufficient money so that there is more than one possible partition of this total into a sum of legal coins.)